# Expresiones regulares para extraer párrafo sin estilos

Tags: php

Mi consulta es como extraer un párrafo que tengo en una variable.

Estoy trabajando con el plug-in Summernote y necesito el texto del párrafo para agregarlo en una tarjeta(card bootstrap) en la página principal, para luego redireccionar a la publicación.

Este es un ejemplo del contenido de la variable, guardado por el plug-in Summernote:

```html
<p style="line-height: 3rem; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; margin-left: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; position: relative; clear: both;">cadena1</p><p style="line-height: 3rem; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; margin-left: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; position: relative; clear: both;"><img src="https://media.cnnchile.com/sites/4/2020/03/La-inversion-en-energias-renovables-se-ralentiza-700x400.jpg" style="width: 700px;"><br></p><h2 class="title" style="line-height: 3rem; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; margin-left: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; font-size: 1.5rem; color: rgb(121, 56, 98); position: relative; clear: both; font-family: &quot;Fira Sans&quot;, &quot;Source Sans Pro&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">Cadena2<a class="genanchor" href="https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string" style="border-bottom: none; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; border-image: initial; color: transparent;">&nbsp;¶</a></h2><p class="para" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; margin-left: 0px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Fira Sans&quot;, &quot;Source Sans Pro&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">Cadena3<span class="type">
```

He estado tratando con expresiones regulares pero ya me duele la cabeza.
He intentado algo como esto:

```
<p(?:.*)>(.*)</p>
```

No funciona...

Comment: ¿No te sirve la función [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me funcionó la función strip_tags();

```html
<div class="card-body">
                <?preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@', $row['editor'], $array);?>
                <img class="card-img-top" height="150" weight="80" src="<? echo array_pop($array); ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                <? $matches = strip_tags($row["editor"], '<p style>');?>
                <p class="card-text"><? echo substr($matches,0,180);?>...</p>
</div>
```

```
$matches = strip_tags($row["editor"], '<p style>');
```

Lo que hice con la función `strip_tags()` fue quitar los estilos
`'<p style>'`, entregando solo el texto, aunque todo junto pero es suficiente ya que solo necesito que se muestren 180 caracteres utilizando la función `substr()`.

Gracias al usuario Triby.